# How do you set the default search engine in firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser

If we type anything in the address bar of firefox, by default the search result comes from bing and if we want to get the result from any desired search engine.
How we can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Firefox.

```
 1. In the address bar, type about:preferences#search and press enter. 

 2. Select Default Search Engine in Drop Down
```

If you want to append more search engines in the drop down list that also you can do by the following steps.

- Click on Add more search engines.
- Hover on the required search engine and click on the Add To Firefox
  button